# How to display the listview at the bottom of my activity ? There are 3 linear layouts above the listview

Tags: android

i am dividing my android screen into four vertical parts and i want to display the listview at the bottom of my screen, but whenever i placed it at bottom it wont aligned to the bottom. Even after i stretched it to the bottom it takes full screen. how to do that ?

Comment: use weightSum with LinearLayout..

Comment: place your code here

Comment: update your question with code.

Answer (score 0):

You can display listview at the bottom by the following desing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <!--First Part--> 

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <!--Second Part-->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <!--Third Part-->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <!--Fourth Part-->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/xListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

this may help you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="4"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
 <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_height="0dp">
    //first view....
 </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_height="0dp">
  //second view....
  </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_height="0dp">
   //third view....
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
    //List view goes here....
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the listview which you want at bottom always need to be seen then you should use rlativelayout. It will help you to place it properly at bottom by using this attribute  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" in your listview.

Answer (score 0):

Linear layout with vertical orientation will be more helpful instead of 
relative layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="4"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
 <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_height="0dp">
 </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_height="0dp">
  </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_height="0dp">
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```